# Finding an inexpensive programmable, cellular data device

Tags: embedded, device

I need to find a device with the following characteristics:

1. Programmable. A few kb of ROM will suffice.
2. Can connect to a cellular data network.
3. Has one digital pin input.
4. Power consumption is not an issue, I can leave it connected to a power supply all day.
5. Inexpensive, below USD$100 per unit.

In other words, I'm looking for something similar to the PIC Ethernet Micro Web device described [here](http://www.sparkfun.com/products/8557) but with a cellular data modem instead of ethernet.

Can anyone suggest where to look for such devices and/or suggest a specific device?

Comment: This is a shopping question and should be closed.

Comment: Well, finding tools/devices is an important part of engineering, how can you design a system without knowing which parts/tools are available and where to get them? It's not like I'm asking where to buy the cheapest iPhone 4...

Comment: I think there is enough here to be acceptable on the site. Where to get them and quantity is localized shopping, but trying to find a component that meets specs is good questions

Comment: I agree, you're not asking about the lowest price for a specific item but this is a bad question period.  You're asking us to find a device ready for purchase that meets an odd mixture of vague requirements (cellular radio for an unknown network and has at least one DIO pin for a button?  Seriously?) at an entirely arbitrary price point.  No, sorry, there is no single black-box solution you can buy to make this happen. Ask a more specific question like 'Where can a hobbyist like me find cellular radios for either GSM or CDMA networks?'  THAT's a good question.

Comment: Edited.      _____________

Comment: @AngryEE it is a perfectly acceptable answer to tell him that a device doesn't exist and tell him an approach to take.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Sparkfun, the [PIC GSM cellular development board](http://www.sparkfun.com/products/8851)   However, this will do SMS data, not 3G data which I'm guessing would be preferred?  Also, it's way outside your price range: $250.  Judging by the fact that just the GSM cellular chips are about $150 by themselves I don't think you're going to hit your price point, especially if you're looking for 3G data.

Now this idea isn't strictly in keeping with your ideal (from what I can tell, a 3G data unit with simple interface or built-in 8/16/32 bit microcontroller), another option might be a simple wireless router with host USB capabilities and a 3G USB modem.  I know that DD-WRT can support these, and probably OpenWRT and/or Tomato.

There's also the [Arduino wifi shield](http://www.cutedigi.com/product_info.php?products_id=4445) for $55 if wifi is acceptable

EDIT:  I looked into the Linux DIO thing, and on my router (Asus WL-500GPv2) there are digital I/O pins that can be accessed via /dev/gpio.  It looks like the setup involves an 'outen' file that specifies which lines are outputs, an 'out' file that lets you set DIO by writing a byte value to it and an 'in' file that can be read to view the current state of the GPIO.  There's a forum post describing it [here](http://wl500g.info/showthread.php?t=19269).

Does anyone else find it fascinating how Linux accesses hardware by reading and writing to it like a bytestream?

Comment: I like the wireless router idea! Do you have any suggestions on how to hack the router into accepting a 1 bit digital input?

Comment: A lot of them already have it present in some fashion (for instance, the reset button on some is a DIO input) but I don't really know how to access it in Linux is the thing.  I can try to look into it a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

Sierra Wireless have pretty much this exact thing:
http://www.sierrawireless.com/productsandservices/AirPrime/Wireless_Modules/Smart.aspx

With a proprietary framework you can run C code on the device. The API relies heavily on callbacks and can be a bit hard to program.

If you want low cost, you could just dismantle a cheap mobile which has a serial connection available. With the right AT commands you can establish a data connection over its UART.